# How to find minima of such functional?

Tags: optimization

How can I find minima of the following functional?

$$J(u)=\int_0^1 (u^2(t)-x^2(t)) \,\mathrm dt \to min$$

$$\dot x(t)= u(t),\ t\in\ [t_0,T],\;x(0)=0 $$

Comment: do you mean $\dot x$: \dot x?

Comment: yeah, thanks about it

Comment: Do you want to find mínima in what space?

Comment: in Real vector space

Comment: What is the domain of your functional $J$?

Comment: no domain is given. It's say: Find the minima $J(u)$..

Comment: @Javidan: I think people are asking you what space does the function $u$ live in. For example, it could be the space $C^1([0,1])$ of differentiable functions on the unit interval. Also, your $t \in [t_0, T]$ is confusing. Why is the interval different than the one implied in the integration bounds? I suggest you take some care to make the question more precise. Until then, I can only tell you that for the choice of space I suggested, the functional is always non-negative and attains minimum $0$ for certain trigonometric functions (this can be determined from Euler-Lagrange equations).

Comment: i am also confused. It's given by high school teacher at exam. Anyway, $J(u)$ can be not functional ? i have no ability to check its correctity for now

Comment: Are you sure the integral isn't $\int_0^\pi$ instead of $\int_0^1$, or something like that?

Comment: @AntonioVargas, sure. I copied all content of problem here